# Unexpected permissions list appear for my app in play store

Tags: android, permissions

I am using this permissions in my app:

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

So why in the app's page in Play Store It is stated that the app can access these:

```
Identity
find accounts on the device
Location
approximate location (network-based)
Photos/Media/Files
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
read the contents of your USB storage
Other:
    draw over other apps
    full network access
    view network connections
    run at startup
    use accounts on the device
```

Where am I using permissions related to "Photos/Media/Files" or "read the contents of your USB storage"?!

Comment: See also [this blog post of mine](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html) further expanding upon the impacts of libraries on apps' permissions.